# PHP7 Type error with interface

Tags: php, symfony

In my symfony project I got an error with a vendor.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to eZ\Publish\Core\MVC\Legacy\Kernel\Loader::setCLIHandler() must implement interface ezpKernelHandler, instance of eZ\Publish\Core\MVC\Legacy\Kernel\CLIHandler given, called in /Users/steve/Projects/Web/BuildSuccess/www/vendor/ezsystems/legacy-bridge/mvc/Kernel/Loader.php on line 237 in /Users/steve/Projects/Web/BuildSuccess/www/vendor/ezsystems/legacy-bridge/mvc/Kernel/Loader.php:255

But this error is strange because I checked and eZ\Publish\Core\MVC\Legacy\Kernel\CLIHandler implements the interface ezpKernelHandler !

```
namespace eZ\Publish\Core\MVC\Legacy\Kernel;

use ezpKernelHandler;

class CLIHandler implements ezpKernelHandler
{
   ...
}
```

I tried to debug, with **get_class** method and I get

```
"eZ\Publish\Core\MVC\Legacy\Kernel\CLIHandler"
```

I also used **class_implements** method and I get

```
array(0) {
}
```

Any idea what append ?

Thanks

Comment: Since `ezpKernelHandler` have no namespace - it probably should be referenced as `\ezpKernelHandler`

Comment: I tried to add \ but got the same error

Comment: is interface ezpKernelHandler in same namespace as CLIHandler?

Answer (score 1):

I see that it is not your code, but rather [eZ Publish](https://github.com/ezsystems/ezpublish-kernel/blob/v2014.11.8/eZ/Publish/Core/MVC/Legacy/Kernel/Loader.php) itself. Because of this it is unlikely that you will be able to update sources, but there is still some things that you can do:

1. Check your Composer autoloader configuration to see that `ezpKernelHandler` class is properly resolved. You may need to register custom autoloader for it.
2. You're most likely receiving this error because you're using Symfony 3.3+ and its recently added [services auto-configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/master/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html) features. You can avoid this error to be thrown by disabling service auto-configuration for affected service, take a look at example [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/service_container.html#services-manually-wire-args)
3. Since this error is fatal but catchable - if nothing else will help you can create your own service factory for this particular service and catch error inside it.

Comment: I tried to disable autowire and autoconfigure but i get the same error. Can you explain how to do the 1. ? Where to check composer autoloader configuration ? What i'm supposed to see ? And how to register a custom autoloader for ezpKernelHandler ? Thanks

Comment: You can use `composer dump-autoload -o` to create optimized class loader, then you can check `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` - it will contain list of all known classes along with paths to them. Check that path is correct. Custom autoloader can be created and registered by using [`spl_autoload_register`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed : https://github.com/ezsystems/LegacyBridge/issues/132

> It is easilly fixed by creating app/autoload.php file which requires both vendor/autoload.php and ezpublish_legacy/autoload.php and changing bin/console to require that file instead of vendor/autoload.php